# Facebook and ActionScript

Tags: flash, facebook, actionscript

I'm using Flash Professional, and my game is coded on that basically. I'm trying to import the web graph-API and tested it on my website, and I still can't get it to work to the point I can't even get a connection.

I run this code at the beginning of a code:

```
Facebook.init("API CODE", handleLogin);
```

Then my login:

```
function login(session:Object, fail:Object):void
{
    if(session != null) {
        player_name = session.user.name;
    }
    else {
        player_name = "failed";
    }
}
```

and nothing happens. Better yet, I use trace and the `handleLogin` is never called, but when I make a Flex document it works. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Where is your `handleLogin` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to use a web-based lib in an ActionScript 3 project, or are you using the [ActionScript 3 Facebook API](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/):

Have you tried one of the examples to get it working?